# Как передать строку в адаптере

Tags: java, android, adapter

У меня есть Adapter в котором из `onBindViewHolder` хочу передать строку в `ViewHolder` но я не пойму как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста что нужно написать.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ItemAmmunitionTestRv Item = itemAmmunitionTestRvs.get(position);

        holder.tv_ammunition.setText(Item.getAmmunitionName());
        holder.string.(сюда нужно написать часть кода которая будет передавать его в ViewHolder)
     
        должно быть что-то типа такого 
        holder.string.setText(Item.getAmmunitionRvFilter()); Но это не работает 
     
    }


  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        
        TextView tv_ammunition;
        RecyclerView rv_ammunition;
        String string;

        private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        private final CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Search");
        AdapterAmmunition adapterAmmunition;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_ammunition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ammunition);
            rv_ammunition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_ammunition);



            RecyclerViewAll(rv_ammunition, string);
        }

        public void RecyclerViewAll(RecyclerView recyclerView, String string) {
            Query query = collectionReference.orderBy(string, Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemSearch> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemSearch>()
                    .setQuery(query, ItemSearch.class).build();

            adapterAmmunition = new AdapterAmmunition(firestoreRecyclerOptions, context);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager RLM_ammunition_all = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
            snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(RLM_ammunition_all);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAmmunition);
            adapterAmmunition.startListening();
            Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.getAdapter()).setStateRestorationPolicy(RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/toc-v2 - рекомендую к ознакомлению.

Comment: Можно в конструктор адаптера передать строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию **bind** во ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_ammunition;
    RecyclerView rv_ammunition;
    String string;

   public void bind(String data){
       // тут связываем данные с вашими view
       // textView.setText(data) и т.д
   }
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_ammunition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ammunition);
        rv_ammunition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_ammunition);


        RecyclerViewAll(rv_ammunition, string);
    }
}
```

Вызывайте её через адаптер, в методе onBindViewHolder обращаясь к вашу холдеру

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String example_data = "Your data";
        holder.bind(example_data);
}
```

P.s *советую почитать книгу "Android программирование для профессионалов", там описывают такие моменты*